# How to show a window where a user can select the app they want to run

Tags: android

I have an app where a user can select a date and then it will open up the calendar then they will add an event or reminder to that.

Right now I am using the `com.google.android.calendar` app. But I am doing a check to see if that is installed. If not it should let them select the app they want to open. Can anyone tell me how I do this? Im nearly certain I heard about something for this but I cant remember for the life of me what its called.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read [this tutorial](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/sending.html).

> Once you have created your Intent and set the extra info, call
>   startActivity() to send it to the system. If the system identifies
>   more than one activity that can handle the intent, it displays a
>   dialog for the user to select which app to use... If there is only one
>   activity that handles the intent, the system immediately starts it.

Also there is an option in this dialog to use selected action by default.

> However, if the action to be performed could be handled by multiple
>   apps and the user might prefer a different app each time—such as a
>   "share" action, for which users might have several apps through which
>   they might share an item—you should explicitly show a chooser dialog...

This chooser dialog is also known as App chooser.

In a few words you can show App chooser with:

```
String title = getResources().getString(R.string.chooser_title);
Intent chooser = Intent.createChooser(intent, title);
if (intent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
    startActivity(chooser);
}
```

Where `intent` is your calendar intent, for example:

```
Intent calendarIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_INSERT, Events.CONTENT_URI);
Calendar beginTime = Calendar.getInstance().set(2012, 0, 19, 7, 30);
Calendar endTime = Calendar.getInstance().set(2012, 0, 19, 10, 30);
calendarIntent.putExtra(CalendarContract.EXTRA_EVENT_BEGIN_TIME, beginTime.getTimeInMillis());
calendarIntent.putExtra(CalendarContract.EXTRA_EVENT_END_TIME, endTime.getTimeInMillis());
calendarIntent.putExtra(Events.TITLE, "New event");
calendarIntent.putExtra(Events.EVENT_LOCATION, "My house");
```

Comment: [This link](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/intents-common.html#Calendar) will give you the extras/ actions that are available to you when creating an implicit calendar intent.

Comment: Thats exactly it. Cheers. Is it possible to then store that choice somehow so they do not have to pick it every time?

Comment: @discodowney If you want to let user set selected application as default then do not use `Intent.createChooser`. Just call `startActivity(intent)` and system shows list of applications that respond to this intent with possibility to set selected application as default. I updated answer, but please read linked tutorial. It has all needed information.